# gwt: creating an instance of Window causes application to hang out

Tags: java, gwt, smartgwt

Inside a legacy application, i am creating a new class MyForm, and modify the existing class MyPanel by adding a reference to MyForm:

```
import com.smartgwt.client.widgets.layout.VLayout;

public class MyPanel extends VLayout 
{
    public static MyForm myForm = null;

    public MyPanel() {
        myForm = new MyForm();//the line causing trouble
    }
}
```

and:

```
public class MyForm extends com.smartgwt.client.widgets.Window 
{

  private static TextItem myTextItem;

  public MyForm()
  {
   //other lines of code
    myTextItem.setValue("some value");
   }
}
```

When commenting  the  initialization of MyForm, the application works as it did before; when i uncomment this line, the application hangs out. The main page of the application is loading forever.

There are no compiler warnings displayed in my IDE (Eclipse), also no error logs/stack trace appear in the log files of the server (Apache Tomcat).

However, the browser console displays the following warning:

> *11:55:42.978:WARN:Log:Uncaught exception escaped: com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException (TypeError) : Cannot
>   read property 'oq' of null
>       at new JEb(ra-0.js)
>       at xHb(ra-0.js)
>       at new EHb(ra-0.js)
>       at iFb(ra-0.js)
>       at UFb(ra-0.js)
>       at XFb(ra-0.js)
>       at aA(ra-0.js)
>       at nd(ra-0.js)
>       at Id(ra-0.js)
>       at eval(ra-0.js)
>       at Gb(ra-0.js)
>       at Jb(ra-0.js)
>       at eval(ra-0.js)

GWT version: 2.8.0
Tomcat version: 8.0

Comment: Check if you have errors in the browser's console.

Comment: I have edited the question by pasting the browser console logs

Comment: Ok, so you are using uninitialized object somewhere in your code, possibly in `MyForm` constructor. You need to know how to debug client code in super dev mode. You can start with Chrome browser, open console, go to Sources tab and click Pause on exceptions icon. Then restart (reload) your application. Good luck!

Comment: I have included some lines of code from the constructor of MyForm, that i have initially omitted because I thought they were not relevant. You were right, it was the myTextItem that was uninstantiated. If you want, please turn your comment into an answer so that i can mark it as accepted