# eclipse: raise compiler warning when using fields that are not initialized

Tags: java, eclipse, nullpointerexception, warnings

In the context of a GWT application ([gwt: creating an instance of Window causes application to hang out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49985693/gwt-creating-an-instance-of-window-causes-application-to-hang-out)), I was setting the value to a text widget which I forgot to initialize, resulting something similar to a null pointer exception in the browser console.

What bothers me is that Eclipse displayed no warnings/errors. So I checked with the following example:

```
Object obj;
//obj = new Object();
obj.toString();
```

Eclipse says:

> The local variable obj may not have been initialized

But when obj is a field of the class, I get no warning:

```
public class MyClass
{
   Object obj;

   public MyClass()
   {
        //obj = new Object();
        obj.toString();// I expect to get some warning here
   }
}
```

I go to Window > Preferences > Java > Compiler > Errors/Warnings, I filter using the text 'null', and the only relevant results are under the section called 'Null analysis'; here, *Null pointer access* is already set to raise a Warning; *Potential null pointer access* is set to Ignore, I modify it to raise a Warning, but i still get no warning for the above example. Is there any other way to tell the compiler to alert me about situations like this?

Comment: Fields initialized with null by default (0 for base types).

Comment: I am aware of that. The problem is the compiler tells nothing when trying to manipulate a field that remained null

Answer (score 0):

I googled a bit and I came across [Eclipse's reporting bug system](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=345332), and I saw this line from the writers:

> An unassigned variable is not assigned by default and the user is expected to assign it in all possible branches of the code, or a compile time error occurs.

And also:

> only fields get a default value. Local variables need to be initialized in all possible paths.

So their line of thinking is that they need you to initialize the variable whenever you need it, and it should be compiler's problem if you haven't done it, and it is no problem as far as lexical, syntax and semantic analyzers are concerned. This is why the warning is not raised.

Comment: regarding your answer, there are 3 things I want to say: 1. I am not interested at all about local variables not being assigned by default; in this case, compiler will raise an error, and I am perfectly fine with this behavior. My question addressed the other aspect - fields with null values and compiler not complaining about that.   2. OK, fields get default values  - which is null in this case; that does not change the problem even a bit: i still have a null field (no matter how it came to be null) and the compiler is not complaining when I manipulate it;

Comment: 3. even if Eclipse website is giving some best practices advice, this behavior can often be overridden in Eclipse settings. That is specifically what i was looking for

Comment: Why should the compiler be concerned about your null field as far as you are not using it?

Comment: I am actually using that field - the moment when i call toString(), or any other method; and I want the compiler to figure out if the field is null by the moment I am using it

Comment: But you are not using it when you are defining it. As long as the compiler is concerned, you have defined it somewhere else, or it's going to be its default value which is `null`.